# Request Error IIS Method call

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I am hosting a WCF Service in my IIS, and I Encountered the error shown below:

> **Request Error**
>
> The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the
> service help page for constructing valid requests to the service. The
> exception message is 'Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\TEST'.'. See
> server logs for more details

I call my method with this link: `http://192.168.1.111/TruckService.svc/getAllCompA`
from the browser I can access the `TruckService.svc` file, only the methods throws an error.

The methods is shown from the **service help** link: `http://192.168.1.111/TruckService.svc/help` Don't know if that would make a difference?

There isn't a lot of info to work with, I did Google the error but cannot seem to find a similar issue.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part of the error message tells you quite a bit, actually:

"The exception message is 'Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\TEST'.'"

You didn't give a whole lot of information in your question, but I'm willing to bet your service is using a SQL database (`Login failed for user` is a fairly common SQL error).

Assuming your connection string is correct, based on the error you're most likely using integrated security, which means that the service is trying to login to SQL with the credentials it's being run under, in this case `IIS APPPOOL\TEST`.

If you want to continue using integrated security, then you need to run the application under an account that has the proper permissions to login to the SQL server.   Alternatively, you can update the connection string to use a user name and password.  Personally, I prefer integrated security.

Finally, did you check server logs for more details as the error suggested?

**Added**

To see/change the account the application pool is running under, go to IIS Manager (either from the start menu or type `inetmgr` from a command prompt).  In the left hand pane, expand the tree view so you see the Application Pools node, and then click on that.

Select the application pool (in your case, `TEST`), right click and select "Advanced Settings..." from the context menu.

This will open a new screen, and you can see what account is currently running that application pool:

[image]

Click on the ellipses (`...`) and this will bring up another window where you can set the account:

[image]

Click the button for Custom account and then click "Set..").

[image]

Finally, enter the account (you will probably need to enter the domain to, like `MyCompany\UserName`), enter the password, confirm the password and click OK.

Note that if the password ever changes, the application pool will not run until the password is updated via the steps above.

Comment: Yes I do have a database in SQL express and running a .net WCF RESTful service. The connection string was created at default when adding the website `data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true`

Comment: @RGdent - `Integrated Security=SSPI` means what I said in my answer - the credentials that the WCF service is running under will be used to login to SQL server, which in this case is the app pool.  The easiest solution is to run the WCF service under an account that has login priveleges for the SQL server.

Comment: Excuse me for my incompetence, how do I see under which account my service is running to view the privileges?